# How do you do a case insensitive search using a pattern modifier using less?

Tags: unix, search, case-insensitive, less-unix

It seems like the only way to do this is to pass the -i parameter in when you initially run less. Does anyone know of some secret hack to make something like this work

```
/something to search for/i
```

Answer (score 517, accepted):

You can also type command `-I` while less is running. It toggles case sensitivity for searches.

Comment: -i means ignore case in searches that do not contain uppercase while -I ignores case in all searches.

Comment: "ignore case in searches that do not contain uppercase" is called "smart case" in vim and ack.  Adding this here for googlability.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye you don't "run a command" just type it, I was confused by the phrasing as well.

Comment: `-I` as in literally type `-I` with less open.

Answer (score 121):

You can also set the environment variable `LESS`

I use `LESS=-Ri`, so that I can pump colorized output from `grep` into it, and maintain the ANSI colour sequences.

Another little used feature of less that I found is starting it with `+F` as an argument (or hitting <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> while in less). This causes it to follow the file you've opened, in the same way that `tail -f <file>` will. Very handy if you're watching log files from an application, and are likely to want to page back up (if it's generating 100's of lines of logging every second, for instance).

Comment: Following with less is SO much more useful than with tail. Especially logs with a lot of action.

Comment: @Svish You could say `less` is more :)

Comment: @MartinKonecny `less` may be more, but `less` is not [`more`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)) let alone [`most`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_(Unix))

Comment: @sanmiguel I didn't know most, tried it and sidescroll is really cool, thanks

Comment: I would use `less +F --follow-name some.file`. `+F` alone not working for me.

Comment: `less` is more than `more`, `most` is more than `less` | `less` is more, but more `more` than `more` is, so `more` is less `less`, so use more `less` if you want less `more`.

Comment: While this works when you start `less` yourself, for things like `hg log` or `git` stuff that use less, this unfortunately doesn't work for me. Luckily remembering `-I` once less is running isn't too bad.

Answer (score 36):

Add-on to what @Juha said: Actually `-i` turns on Case-insensitive with SmartCasing, i.e if your search contains an uppercase letter, then the search will be case-sensitive, otherwise, it will be case-insensitive. Think of it as `:set smartcase` in Vim.

E.g.: with `-i`, a search for 'log' in 'Log,..' will match, whereas 'Log' in 'log,..' will not match.

Comment: Actually, if *any* letter, not just the first one, is uppercase the search will be case sensitivite. An important difference (and indicentally how I prefer it to be). This is also how vim's smartcase works.

Comment: In Vim you can also say `/\clog` to switch to case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 15):

It appears that you can summon this feature on a per search basis like so:

```
less prompt> /search string/-i
```

This option is in `less`'s interactive help which you access via `h`:

```
less prompt> h
...
  -i  ........  --ignore-case
                  Ignore case in searches that do not contain uppercase.
  -I  ........  --IGNORE-CASE
                  Ignore case in all searches.
...
```

I've not extensively checked but the help in `less` version 487 on MacOS as well as other Linux distros lists this option as being available.

On MacOS you can also install a newer version of `less` via `brew`:

```
$ brew install less
$ less --version
less 530 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2017  Mark Nudelman
```

#### References

- [less is always case-insensitive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116395/less-is-always-case-insensitive/116401#116401)

Comment: @IlikeSerena - it may be an issue w/ specific versions of `less`.

Comment: @slm which `less` did you try this on ? Doen't work on my `less 458 (GNU regular expressions)` (aptitude says `less 458-2` FWIW)

Comment: @hdl - I do not have access to the system currently but was on whatever version of `less` that's included w/ Fedora 19/20.

Comment: @slm Thanks, probably a more recent release than 458-2, such as 458-6 as this particular one was built for Fedora on 2014-02-10 according to http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=759 and since you posted this on Feb 22 '14...

Comment: Doesn't work on mac with less 487 (POSIX regular expressions)

Comment: @SumitJain - you could try installing newer version of less on MacOS, see updates. NOTE: that the `-i` switch is listed in version 487's help.

Comment: This doesn't work with `less 590 (GNU regular expressions)` in Ubuntu

Answer (score 12):

When using -i flag, be sure to enter the search string completely in lower case, because if any letter is upper case, then its an exact match.

See also:  the -I (capital i) flag of less(1) to change this behavior.