# Linux : less cannot search case insensitive using -i

Tags: linux, less-unix

Consider:

[image]

If searching using `?cm02csdate -i`, it fails:

[image]

But if searching using `?CM02CSDATE`, it can be found:

[image]

[image]

I searched the man page. It also said using `-i` to search case insensitive, as the following shows:

[image]

So why does it fail when I use `?cm02csdate -i`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you do a case insensitive search using a pattern modifier using less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828/how-do-you-do-a-case-insensitive-search-using-a-pattern-modifier-using-less)

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73744517/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-i` flag should be given to `less`. I.e. `less -i <filename>` or `some_program | less -i`.